# .Net Maui - How to go back to root page

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I feel like I'm just not asking this question right to the Google overlord, so I'm going to see if someone can help explain how to do this. I have a new .Net Maui app that uses 4 different views/pages. The MainPage (root) I created lets me search for a user from our database and then transitions you to a new page; which I call the ResultsPage. From there, you can select a user and be taken to a DetailPage where edits can be performed. Once you make your edits and save, it sends you to my final page (SuccessPage) with a message about the changes.

This all works like a charm. I'm able to use ViewModels and QueryProperties to pass the data around to the pages and it saves the changes to the database. Where it fails is on the SuccessPage. After you get the message about the updates, I want to have a button where the user would then go right back to the MainPage and could perform a new search and repeat all the steps above.

For all the other page transitions, I'm able to leverage `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` to get to the new page and/or pass data, like so:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ResultsPage));
```

or

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(DetailsPage)}?Parameter={param}");
```

From the Success Page, I tried putting `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MainPage));`, but this throws an exception about "relative routing to shell elements not currently being supported" and suggests I try prefixing /// to my uri. I try that, but the only thing that changes is the page title; it doesn't actually restore the MainPage UI elements. So how can I get the shell to go back to the MainPage?

Additionally, I've also tried `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`, but get the same problem like when I prefixed the slashes to the uri; it changes the title but doesn't change any UI elements

**Edit**

For reference, here is the code behind for the button (note: I left my commented out attempts with remarks beside them showing how they didn't help

```
private async void ReturnSearchButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../"); //exception, ambiguous routes matched

        //List<Page> previousPages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
        //foreach (Page page in previousPages)
        //{
        //  Navigation.RemovePage(page); //exception, null value
        //}

        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    }
```

Here's some screenshots of the UI before and after the button is clicked:

*Before button clicked*
[image: Before button press]

*After button clicked*
[image: After button pressed]

**MainPage addition edit**

*MainPage XAML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UserNameReset.Views.MainPage"
             Title="Home">
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10"
                         Margin="5">

        <Label 
            Text="Reset Users"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Text="Enter the users email address or their ID with Pin" 
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="18"/>

        <Label
            x:Name="fullWarningLabel"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="18"
            TextColor="Red"
            Text="You must provide either the users email OR their ID and pin"
            IsVisible="false"/>

        <Entry 
            x:Name="emailEntry"
            Placeholder="example@demo.org"
            ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
            Completed="Entry_Completed"
            Keyboard="Email"
            IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"/>

        <Label
            Text="OR"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="18"/>

        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" ColumnSpacing="4" RowDefinitions="*,*" RowSpacing="2">
            <Entry
                x:Name="idEntry"
                Placeholder="ID"
                ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Completed="Entry_Completed"
                IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"/>
            <Label
                x:Name="idWarning"
                IsVisible="false"
                Text="Please enter the users ID"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="2"
                TextColor="Red"/>

            <Entry
                x:Name="pinEntry"
                Placeholder="PIN"
                ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Completed="Entry_Completed"
                IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"/>
            <Label
                x:Name="pinWarning"
                IsVisible="false"
                Text="Please enter the users PIN"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="2"
                TextColor="Red"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button
            x:Name="SubmitButton"
            Text="Search"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Click to search for the user by values you provided"
            Clicked="Entry_Completed"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

*MainPage code behind*

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UserNameReset.Models;

namespace UserNameReset.Views;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly ILogger<MainPage> _logger;

    public MainPage(ILogger<MainPage> logger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the user clicks the "Search" button, 
    /// when they finish entering an email,
    /// or when they successfully enter both Id and Pin
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Entry fields filled, checking values...");

        // Cleans up layout each time search is triggered
        pinWarning.IsVisible = false;
        idWarning.IsVisible = false;
        fullWarningLabel.IsVisible = false;

        bool validUser = false;
        bool usingPinAndId = false;
        Queried_User user = new();

        // Check that both the plant ID and PIN were provided
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idEntry.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pinEntry.Text))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Pin and ID provided!");
            validUser = true;
            usingPinAndId = true;
            user.Pin = pinEntry.Text;
            user.Id = idEntry.Text;
        }
        // Check if the email was provided (only if the plant ID and PIN weren't)
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailEntry.Text))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Email provided!");
            validUser = true;
            user.Email = emailEntry.Text;
        }
        // If nothing was provided, add a warning to the appropriate entry fields
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plantIdEntry.Text))
                pinWarning.IsVisible = true;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pinEntry.Text))
                idWarning.IsVisible = true;
            else
                fullWarningLabel.IsVisible = true;
        }

        // Did we get a valid user obj? Navigate to the results page if so
        if (validUser)
        {
            // create a message of how the search is proceeding, changing text depending on search method
            string msg = "Searching via " + (usingPinAndId ? "plant ID: (" + user.Id + ") and pin: (" + user.Pin + ")" : "email: (" + user.Email + ")");


            _logger.LogInformation("User info validated. Going to get results from DB. " + msg);
            GoToResults(msg, user);
        }

        // Useful for displaying alerts or messages to the end user!!
        //await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", $"Undable to return records: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a simple user object and then redirects the user to the results page, 
    /// passing the user object as a query property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    private async void GoToResults(string srchMthd, Queried_User user)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"User properties - email:{user.Email} - pin:{user.Pin} - ID:{user.Id}");

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ResultsPage)}?SearchMethod={srchMthd}",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["User"] = user
            });
    }
}
```

**GitHub update**

I created a repo which hosts a simplified version of the application that duplicates this issue: [GitHub](https://github.com/toxictouch/BuggyMaui)

**Edit 2022-10-6**

Due to suggestions from others, I have opened a new issue with the Maui GitHub for this problem. To see that issue and follow its progress, go [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10533)

Comment: Let me understand you, you need to popToRootAsync but with a new instance of your main page? with no changes on the ui right?

Comment: I believe so, I want the UI elements from the main page to show up if I popToRootAsync. All it does right now is change the title at the top, but keeps the UI from the previous page (success page)

Comment: I'll add some screenshots and the codebehind for the button handler to see if that helps, hang on

Comment: What does your MainPage look like?

Comment: Have you tried this on another platform other than Windows? Just asking, because maybe there is a bug

Comment: I just added the codebehind and xaml for the MainPage. I haven't tried it on another platform yet, ideally we are only planning to use it on Windows (eventually maybe adding to iOS or android) . But I'll try and get the android emulator running and see how it works now

Comment: what this the relation between your MainPage and Shell? how your AppShell.xaml is defined ?

Comment: MainPage is the only one listed in the AppShell on the xaml side (as ShellContent). The other three pages are defined in the AppShell constructor like this: `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameoff(ResultsPage), typeof(ResultsPage));`. Let me know if snippets of that above would be beneficial

Comment: For the heck of it, here's the shellcontent of MainPage in AppShell:

`<ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />`

Comment: Could you upload a reproduction sample repo to github? where you only keep the essential code that of course reproduce the issue. it will be easier to test and help you.

Comment: Yea I can do that, might take me a bit but I'll get it up before the day is out

Comment: thanks, no issue take your time

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. I have created a repo now that duplicates the issue. The link is at the bottom of the post above and also here: https://github.com/toxictouch/BuggyMaui

Comment: Please report this to the MAUI team as an issue on GitHub, because it looks like a bug. It's great that you have a repo, you should provide the link in the issue as well. Just go to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues and create a new issue using the Bug Report template

Comment: @ewerspej Sounds good, I'll try and get the issue reported over lunch (if not then, I will as soon as I get home from work). Out of curiosity, once I file the issue should I update this post to link to the issue or will that matter?

Comment: I think it was already reported [look at this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950551/net-maui-how-to-go-back-to-root-page?noredirect=1#comment130606763_73955607)

Comment: I was under the impression it would get reported in two place. That comment states it was reported to the *inner channel*,  but it sounds like I also need to report it to the (public?) GitHub channel. I could be mistaken though. Do you think I should still try to report it on GitHub?

Comment: Yes, we usually suggest op report the bug to the github because we just report a bug by the inner channel and it will not appear on the github. So it always needs op to report it on the github and a new issue will be opened. @StanMan3

Comment: It has now been reported. See my edit above for a link to the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get some help directly from Microsoft Support regarding this issue. Their support suggested I try to pop to the root page using this in the xaml code-behind:

```
while (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[1]);
}

await dispatcherProvider.DispatchAsync(() => Shell.Current.GoToAsync(".."));
```

The while loop cycles through the pages in the navigation stack and removes them one-by-one before using the dispatcher to GoToAsync(). In addition to having the above code in an event handler, you'll want to add the following as a global variable and assignment in the constructor:

```
private readonly IDispatcher dispatcherProvider;
public ActionPage(ActionViewModel vm, IDispatcher dispatcher)
{
    BindingContext = vm;
    dispatcherProvider = dispatcher;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Support and I both agreed that the documentation is confusing on *what* is required to perform such a simple function. But this solution at least worked the way I needed it too and hopefully will help others who find themselves in the same predicament

Comment: The solution works. Thank you very much. However it is missing the backward animation. Do you have any idea how get the animation back?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a new sample to test, and try to use the `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();` and `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");` to navigate to the root page. Both of them showed the mainpage's title but didn't show the page's content.

So I clicked the button on the tool bar to see the live visual tree and found when I get back to the main page, there was only the mainpage in it. And then I try to run it on the android platform, it worked correctly. This should be a display bug when user gets to the rootpage on the windows platform.

You can try to report it to the maui on the github.

Comment: Since (a) you already created a minimal example and (b) you are a Microsoft employee, wouldn't it be better if you created the bug report yourself? It strikes my as strange that an employee of company A who reproduces a bug in a product of company A would then ask *a random stranger on the Internet* to create the bug report!

Comment: I had reported it by the inner channel. And the github is a platform for all the developers.  @Heinzi

Comment: *"I had reported it by the inner channel."* Ah, ok, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: What would be even better is to include a link to the issue you have filled so that devs affected by this issue could interact and track it progress.

Comment: The bug reported by the inner channel will not appear on the github. @Cfun

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting "relative routing to shell elements not currently being supported", 9 of 10 cases, you forgot to add it to your shell or register it.

In the AppShell.xaml you need ShellItem with ShellContent of the Page.
And in AppShell.xaml.cs you need Routing.RegisterRoute(..)

Then you will be able to call navigation with "//".

Try it.

Edit: Just to be on the same page, this will not magically clear your UI. The page is not reconstructed when you navigate to it.

Comment: All four pages are already registered in one of these manners. The MainPage is registered in the AppShell (xaml side) as `<ShellContent />` and the other three are registered on the back-side using `Routing.RegisterRoute(..);`

Comment: @StanMan3 If you want to use "//" for specific page, it has to be in the AppShell xaml as ShellItem with ShellContent. And in the AppShell cs file, as registred route. I am using Login page, that has to be navigated with "//" in my app, and adding it like that allowed this type of navigation. Otherwise I was getting your error. (You need it not in one of those manners, but in both)

Comment: that's confusing. I mean I get the logic, defining each shell page and then defining the routes to the shell pages. But none of the documentation I read or watched (shoutout to James Montemagno) made it sound like that is the **normal** manner of adding routes or pages. Where did you find documentation that outlines this?

Comment: I did not find any documentation about this. I was fighting this problem when implementing login flow (and had to navigate to pages with "//"), found out what is causing this exception you are getting, and now decided to share my experience.