# .NET MAUI: Redirect to a page previously viewed

Tags: .net, maui

How to go back to a page if it was previously viewed?
As an example, I took James Montemagno's program (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MauiApp-DI).
It consists of 3 pages: MainPage, DetailsPage and AnotherPage.
How can I jump from AnotherPage directly to the MainPage? When calling

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../{nameof(MainPage)}");
```

the program crashes.

(I assume AnotherPage doesn't know where it is in the hierarchy.)

Comment: You cannot navigate to `MainPage` with relative navigation, because it's your root. You can simply use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");` to go back one level in the navigation stack.

Comment: That's a go back. But if you've gone through multiple pages and want to jump back to the MainPage from there, that won't work.

Comment: You need to know how many levels to go back with this approach, but you can only do relative navigation when you know how many pages are on the stack, anyway. To go back two levels, you would do `GoToAsync("../..")`, etc. You could also try `Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();` followed by any other navigation. What you've tried in your example would lead to a navigation stack with `MainPage` on top of the root, which is also `MainPage`, which is not allowed. BTW, this question deals with a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950551/net-maui-how-to-go-back-to-root-page

Comment: [OPINION] I consider custom navigation like this to be easier to code using `NavigationPage` instead of `Shell`. NavigationPage maintains a stack of pages that you can manipulate. In this case, write code that searches the stack for page of the desired type, and remove all pages pushed after it. I've done this succcessfully for years, long before shell came along.