# MAUI Google Play Console. Exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

Google play console return from report information about 4 ANR failures and errors.
Which occurred on devices: google Pixel 5, xiaomi Redmi 6A, Generic Small Desktop (x86), Google Pixel 2.
From the videos, which are attached to the reports, it seems that all these errors occur during, return to the start page. But this is not the first attempt to return, in addition, it does not always return from the same page and does not perform the same actions before returning. I use such code snippets to return to the start page:

```
(App.Current as App).MainPage = new AppShell(); 
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($".", false);
```

In the stack trece that returns me google play console there is no information about the controls from my app. Looks like some MAUI error, not my code. I have seen some similar stack trace and problems on github, but there were no solutions for these problems.

I have updated all NuGets but the problem still occurs.
I also did a test where I commented out the

```
(App.Current as App).MainPage = new AppShell();
```

I use this piece of code when I change the language in my application. But there were still 2 errors in the reports. Although sometimes there are fewer of these devices, and sometimes more so I'm not sure if this changed anything.

I attache stack trace:

> Exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ObjectDisposedException: ObjectDisposed_Generic
> ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name, Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiMaterialButton
> at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf(IJavaPeerable )
> at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(String , IJavaPeerable , JniArgumentValue* )
> at Android.Views.View.SetOnClickListener(IOnClickListener )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.DisconnectHandler(MaterialButton )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IButton, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Google.Android.Material.Button.MaterialButton, Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnDisconnectHandler(View ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnDisconnectHandler(Object ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.DisconnectHandler(Object ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler.DisconnectHandler() at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler ) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler ) at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement , IMauiContext ) at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement , IMauiContext ) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.UpdateContent() at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.<>c.<.cctor>b__67_6(FrameRenderer , Frame ) at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].b__0(IElementHandler , IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String , IElementHandler , IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler , IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement , IPlatformViewHandler , Action`1 , Frame& , IPropertyMapper& , IPropertyMapper , Boolean )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewHandlerDelegator`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement , Action`1 , Boolean )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement , IMauiContext )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement , IMauiContext )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement ) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler ) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler ) at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement , IMauiContext ) at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement , IMauiContext ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler , IContentView ) at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].b__0(IElementHandler , IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String , IElementHandler , IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler , IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView ) at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement , IMauiContext )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ViewExtensions.ToHandler(IView , IMauiContext )
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellFragmentContainer.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater , ViewGroup , Bundle )
> at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr )
> at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr )
> at crc640ec207abc449b2ca.ShellFragmentContainer.n_onCreateView
> at crc640ec207abc449b2ca.ShellFragmentContainer.onCreateView (ShellFragmentContainer.java:41)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:3104)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java:524)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:261)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:1899)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:1817)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1729)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow (BackStackRecord.java:317)
> at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder (FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
> at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow (FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
> at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow (FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached (RecyclerView.java:7867)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView (RecyclerView.java:893)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView (ChildHelper.java:107)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt (RecyclerView.java:8902)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView (RecyclerView.java:8860)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView (RecyclerView.java:8848)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1645)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java:4309)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout (RecyclerView.java:4012)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout (RecyclerView.java:4578)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout (ViewPager2.java:527)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:149)
> at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild (ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
> at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild (AppBarLayout.java:2253)
> at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java:953)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1263)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal (LinearLayout.java:1818)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1584)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:784)
> at android.view.View.layout (View.java:22844)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6389)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2943)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8177)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:972)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:796)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:731)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:957)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: You can check the answer about [how to navigate to the root page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74102989/19335715) by using the `IDispatcher`.